# Same function in function, preserve variables/elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a javascript function which creates a modal. Here's the function:

```
    function createModal(options) {
        var self = this;
        modalHeaderText = options.header;
        modalBodyText = options.body;
        $modal = $('<div />').addClass('modal').appendTo('body');
        $modalOverlay = $('<div />').addClass('modal-overlay').appendTo($modal);
        $modalContainer = $('<div />').addClass('modal-container').appendTo($modal);
        $modalHeader = $('<div />').addClass('modal-header').addClass(options.headerClass).html(modalHeaderText).appendTo($modalContainer);
        $modalBody = $('<div />').addClass('modal-body').addClass(options.bodyClass).html(modalBodyText).appendTo($modalContainer);
        if (options.buttons) {
            $modalFooter = $('<div />').addClass('modal-footer').appendTo($modalContainer);
            $.each(options.buttons, function(name, buttonOptions) {
                $modalButton = $('<button />').addClass(buttonOptions.class).html(name).appendTo($modalFooter);
                if(buttonOptions.callback) {
                    $modalButton.on('click', function() { 
                        buttonOptions.callback(); 
                    });
                } else {
                    $modalButton.on('click', function(e) { 
                        $modal.remove();
                    });
                };
            });
        };
        $modal.addClass('active');
        if (options.closeOnOverlayClick == true) {
            $modalOverlay.on('click', function(e) {
                $modal.remove();
            });
        };
    };
```

This works fine, but I want to be able to call the function within the same function, like this:

```
    $('#modal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        createModal({
            header      : 'Enter your name',
            body        : '<input type="text" class="name" />',
            buttons     : {
                'OK'    : {
                    class : 'btn btn-success',
                    callback : function() {
                        var name = self.$modalBody.find('.name').val();
                        if (!name) {
                            createModal({
                                header      : 'Error',
                                body        : 'You must provide a name',
                                buttons     : {
                                    'OK'    : {
                                        class : 'btn'
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert(name);
                        };
                    },
                },
                'Close' : {
                    class : 'btn btn-error'
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

What I want is the following: when someone clicks the button with ID "modal" (hence "#modal"), a modal is opened with a input. When the OK-button is pressed, it checks if the input ('name') has a value. If so, the value is shown in an alert. If not, a new modal is openend (over the current modal) with the text 'You must provide a name'.

If I enter a name, it works. The name is shown in an alert, and also the close button works. But if I do not enter a name, and the second modal is shown, all the variables in the function are overwritten.

How can I preserve the variables/elements from the first modal so that, after the second modal is shown (and cleared), the buttons from the first modal still work.

I've created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6pq7ce0a/2/

You can test it like this:

1) click on 'open modal'
2) enter a name
3) click on 'ok'
4) the name is shown in an alert
==> this works

The problem is here:

1) click on 'open modal'
2) do NOT enter a name
3) click on 'ok'
4) a new modal is shown
5) click on 'ok' in the new (error) modal
6) the buttons from the first modal (with the input field) don't work anymore

Thanks in advance!

### Update

If I change the function to the function below, the first modal does not work at all.

```
    function createModal(options) {
        var self = this;
        var modalHeaderText = options.header;
        var modalBodyText = options.body;
        var $modal = $('<div />').addClass('modal').appendTo('body');
        var $modalOverlay = $('<div />').addClass('modal-overlay').appendTo($modal);
        var $modalContainer = $('<div />').addClass('modal-container').appendTo($modal);
        var $modalHeader = $('<div />').addClass('modal-header').addClass(options.headerClass).html(modalHeaderText).appendTo($modalContainer);
        var $modalBody = $('<div />').addClass('modal-body').addClass(options.bodyClass).html(modalBodyText).appendTo($modalContainer);
        if (options.buttons) {
            var $modalFooter = $('<div />').addClass('modal-footer').appendTo($modalContainer);
            $.each(options.buttons, function(name, buttonOptions) {
                var $modalButton = $('<button />').addClass(buttonOptions.class).html(name).appendTo($modalFooter);
                if(buttonOptions.callback) {
                    $modalButton.on('click', function() { 
                        buttonOptions.callback(); 
                    });
                } else {
                    $modalButton.on('click', function(e) { 
                        $modal.remove();
                    });
                };
            });
        };
        $modal.addClass('active');
        if (options.closeOnOverlayClick == true) {
            $modalOverlay.on('click', function(e) {
                $modal.remove();
            });
        };
    };
```

The problem is here:

```
var name = self.$modalBody.find('.name').val();
```

$modalBody is not defined if I add 'var' to all the elements.

Comment: Your issue is that most of the variables in your method are not defined as `var variableName`.  Without the `var` preceding the variable name when you create it, it will be a global and changed any time that method is called.  If you properly scope those variables down to the method, multiple calls to the method will not affect one another.

Comment: I tried this by adding 'var' to all of the elements I declare (like $modal, $modalBody, ... ). But then the first modal does not work anymore. Weird... (see my updated question).

Comment: Why not creating two separate functions?

Comment: If you open your developer tools you will see it is complaining about a `find()` not working.  This is because you are doing `var name = self.$modalBody.find('.name').val();`  Instead of trying to do `self` there, pass the `$modalBody` into the callback from the other method, and use that function argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in addition to the comments above regarding not declaring `var` you also are storing a reference to `window` in the self variable. To avoid all of that I went down the road in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10fanzw6/1/.

Quick explanation.

- First don't assign `this` to `self` as `this` is window
- Second assign everything to the empty `self` object as well as a local var (for better readability)
- Third pass the `self` var back to any button callback giving you access to any part of the modal you may need.

For posterity, including the updated function here:

```js
function createModal(options) {
  var self = {};
  var modalHeaderText = options.header;
  var modalBodyText = options.body;
  var $modal = self.$modal = $('<div />').addClass('modal').appendTo('body');
  var $modalOverlay = self.$modalOverlay = $('<div />').addClass('modal-overlay').appendTo($modal);
  var $modalContainer = self.$modalContainer = $('<div />').addClass('modal-container').appendTo(self.$modal);
  self.$modalHeader = $('<div />').addClass('modal-header').addClass(options.headerClass).html(modalHeaderText).appendTo($modalContainer);
  self.$modalBody = $('<div />').addClass('modal-body').addClass(options.bodyClass).html(modalBodyText).appendTo($modalContainer);
  if (options.buttons) {
    var $modalFooter = self.$modalFooter = $('<div />').addClass('modal-footer').appendTo($modalContainer);
    $.each(options.buttons, function(name, buttonOptions) {
      var $modalButton = $('<button />').addClass(buttonOptions.class).html(name).appendTo($modalFooter);
      if (buttonOptions.callback) {
        $modalButton.on('click', function() {
          buttonOptions.callback(self);
        });
      } else {
        $modalButton.on('click', function(e) {
          $modal.remove();
        });
      };
    });
  };
  $modal.addClass('active');
  if (options.closeOnOverlayClick == true) {
    $modalOverlay.on('click', function(e) {
      $modal.remove();
    });
  };
};
$('#modal').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  createModal({
    header: 'Enter your name',
    body: '<input type="text" class="name" />',
    buttons: {
      'OK': {
        class: 'btn btn-success',
        callback: function(modal) {
          var name = modal.$modalBody.find('.name').val();
          if (!name) {
            createModal({
              header: 'Error',
              body: 'You must provide a name',
              buttons: {
                'OK': {
                  class: 'btn'
                }
              }
            });
          } else {
            alert(name);
          };
        },
      },
      'Close': {
        class: 'btn btn-error'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this very helpful answer! It works. Also thank you for the explanation, I understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply not using `var` in front of `$modal` variable causing it to be stored in window scope. When the next next $modal is closed, the variable is referencing to an already removed element, so nothing happens on first modal's `Close` button click.